# interface IComparer Error No overload for method 'Sort' takes 2 arguments

Tags: c#, interface

I should call Interface's method Sort in other Class, which included List
But I can't find right solution, though i make by example my teacher.

Error: No overload for method 'Sort' takes 2 arguments.

Class Student:Person

```
 public class SortByName : IComparer
        {
            int IComparer.Compare(object obj1, object obj2)
            {
                Student st1 = (Student)obj1;
                Student st2 = (Student)obj2;
                return st1.Name.CompareTo(st2.Name);
            }
        }
```

class AcademyGroup:

```
    List<Student> group;    
    --------//---------
    public void Sort()
            {
                   group.Sort (group, new Student.SortByName());
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the call of `Sort` is that you are trying to pass `group` twice - once as the target of the call to the left of `.`, and one more time as the first parameter of the method.

There is also a problem with the implementation of the interface: you should implement the generic version.

This will fix the problem:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
...
public class SortByName : IComparer<Student> {
    public int Compare(Student st1, Student st2) {
        return st1.Name.CompareTo(st2.Name);
    }
}
...
group.Sort(new Student.SortByName());
```

Note that `IComparer<T>` is a member of `System.Collections.Generic` namespace, while `IComparer` that you used is a member of `System.Collections` namespace. You need to change the `using` directive, or fully qualify the declaration if you need the non-generic version as well.

Comment: Instead of specifying either non-generic interface `IComparer` or the generic `IComparer<Student>` it can be a good idea to inherit instead from the `abstract` base class `Comparer<Student>` instead. Still just one method you need to supply. In this way your class will become *both* an `IComparer` and an `IComparer<>`, and the base class gives you the necessary type-checking for free.

Comment: You can even create an instance of `Comparer<Student>` with just a lambda. That goes `var sortByName = Comparer<Student>.Create((st1, st2) => st1.Name.CompareTo(st2.Name));`.

Answer (score 0):

[`List<T>.Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes a generic `IComparer<T>`, not a non-generic `IComparer`. Make your comparer generic:

```
    public class SortByName : IComparer<Student>
    {
        int IComparer.Compare(Student st1, Student st2)
        {
            return st1.Name.CompareTo(st2.Name);
        }
    }
```

Also, you don't need to pass `group` as an argument to `group.Sort`, just pass the comparer:

```
group.Sort (new Student.SortByName());
```

Comment: i fix, but i've : Error: The non-generic type 'System.Collections.IComparer' cannot be used with type arguments

Comment: @AleksandrFursenko: You forgot to put `using System.Collections.Generic;` at the top of your file.

Comment: I' sorry but it include: using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

Comment: @AleksandrFursenko You should remove `System.Collections`, too.